# Как можно брать строку из файла для каждого потока в multiprocessing отдельно?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, многопоточность

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не могу для каждого отдельного потока в multiprocessing брать отдельную строку из файла. Получается только брать строку одну строку для всех потоков одновременно.

Т.е я хочу, чтобы:
Первый поток = бралась первая строка файла;
Второй поток = бралась вторая строка файла, и т.д.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pyperclip
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import multiprocessing

password = "12345"

with open("Token.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]

def get_data(url):
    try:
        service = Service(r"D:\pythonProject\TestMnogopotok\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_extension(
            "metamask.crx")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
        driver.get(url=url)
        time.sleep(5)

        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        driver.get("chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/home.html")
        time.sleep(2)

        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        driver.get("chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/home.html")
        time.sleep(2)

        start_metamask_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                    '//*[@id="app-content"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/button').click()
        time.sleep(3)
        import_wallet = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                            '//*[@id="app-content"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/button').click()
        time.sleep(3)
        agreed = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                     '//*[@id="app-content"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/div[1]/footer/button[2]').click()
        time.sleep(3)

        select_word_phrase = Select(
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app-content"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[2]/select'))
        select_word_phrase.select_by_visible_text('I have a 24-word phrase')
        time.sleep(3)
        # Вставить фразу
        search_elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="import-srp__srp-word-0"]').click()
        time.sleep(2)

        pyperclip.copy(content)
        print(content)

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_count = 3
    url = 'chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/home.html'
    urls_list = [url] * process_count
    print(urls_list)
    p = Pool(processes=process_count)
    p.map(get_data, urls_list)
```

Comment: Если у вас проблема с множественным доступом к ресурсу, то почему не решить, например, с использованием RLock? Он для этого и предназначен, в общем-то:-)